# How are the default Execution Modes set up in WinEdt?

Tags: miktex, winedt

I'm using portable MiKTeX and when I set up the *Execution Modes* pointing to it, it works just fine. However, every time I change the computer the defaults are reverted to the `C:\` drive and I have to set the *Execution Modes* over again (say by loading `TeXConfig.edt` from the flash drive). Also, the `default.prj` isn't coming up automatically and I have to specially load it. How are these defaults set once and for all in WinEdt?

Comment: I could never figure out how to set up those defaults and am wondering if it's at all possible to do that?

Comment: As it stands, this seems like a very narrow case.